# Wait till API call returns data in Angular

Tags: angular, donut-chart

I have a Donut chart that is loaded with data that is returned from three API calls. I have called the chart load, and API calls function in ngOninit(). But my chart does not load. I understand that in Angular, execution does not wait for API call to return data and that it continues to execute the rest of the program. Is there some way to wait till the API call returns the data and then load the chart?

**TS**

```
ngOnit(){
 this.refreshDoneCount_DE();
    this.refreshNotDoneCount_DE();
    this.refreshPendingCount_DE();
    this.refreshChart();

}

refreshDoneCount_DE(){
  this.dashboard.get_done_count_de_api().subscribe(data=>{
     this.done_count_de=data;
  });
}

refreshNotDoneCount_DE(){
  this.dashboard.get_notdone_count_de_api().subscribe(data=>{
     this.not_done_count_de=data;
  });
}

refreshPendingCount_DE(){
  this.dashboard.get_pending_count_de_api().subscribe(data=>{
    this.pending_count_de=data;
  });
}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you have routing in place use resolve https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve this will hold your HTML to render until your API call is finished.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar situation in the past, so I designed the chart in the following lines,

1. Put a spinner in the page until API returns the data,
2. Ensure you assign the received values and change the object reference otherwise your chart re-render will not trigger,

something like below,

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.yourService.someMethod().subscribe(value => {
  this.someInstanceVariable = value; //Initially make it undefined, once data arrived assign the value
  this.chartData.series = value.data;
  this.chartData = {...this.chartData};
 }
 )
}
```

When you execute this line `this.chartData = {...this.chartData};` it will help your chart rerender after data arrival.

In the HTML make it like this,

```
<div *ngIf="!someInstanceVariable">
  <chart-lib ...></chart-lib>
</div>

<div *ngIf="someInstanceVariable">
  <div><!--spinner logic --></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 1:**

Based on edit, I assume that user needs to be notified when all these observables complete,

```
forkJoin(
this.dashboard.get_done_count_de_api(),
this.dashboard.get_notdone_count_de_api(),
this.dashboard.get_pending_count_de_api()
).subscribe(
combinedValue=>{
//combinedValue will be an array of values received from all three apis in the order they appear inside the forkJoin() function
}
);
```

Comment: Hi, I have three API calls, so shoud I nest the them?

Comment: well its difficult to answer until I know your functionality, if you have them in series or in parallel? Show me your ts code I may be able to help better

Comment: I have added the code to my question.

Comment: Its even confusing do you want to combine all the values emitted by APIs? The way you have written code, your chart will only have last values depicted out of all the three apis. I guess you need to combine them in one and use the emitted values at last and do your computation. Let me know if yes I can write this code snippet for you

Comment: Yes, please provide a code snippet.

Comment: have a look in the answer, and if this helps you please don't forget to upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to "surrender" to the async nature of HTTP requests instead of waiting for responses.

in a standard async handling pattern, instead of waiting you subscribe to the response.

Service

```
  fetchData () {
    return http.get('your-api-url');
  }
```

component:

```
 ngOnInit() {
   this.yourService.fetchData().subscribe(data => {
   
     // your code to handle the chart goes here
     // this is only called when fetchData responds, so no need to write code to wait.

   });
 }
```